# SAP UI5 Cross Application Navigation without FLP

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I have two apps. The first app has a view. There I push a button and then it should change to the second application. I don't want to navigate to the first view, but to the second with a parameter.

I use this:

```
oCrossAppNavigator.toExternal({
    target : {  
               semanticObject : "Z_APP2",
               action : "onPress"
             }, 
    params : {
               param1 : param1
             }
```

In APP2 I write this in the Component.js:

```
var oRouter = this.getRouter().initialize();
        var oComponentData = this.getComponentData();
        if (oComponentData.startupParameters) {
            oRouter.navTo("Detail", {
                param1 : oComponentData.startupParameters.param1[0],
            }, false);
```

It doesn't switch to the other app. Which action should I write here ? 
Do I have to implement something else in App2?

Comment: Did you configure semantic object at the back-end? Did you configure the corresponding target in Fiori launchpad?

Comment: Yeah i create a BSP Application and standalone it works fine. I also add this code <script src="resources/sap/ushell_abap/bootstrap/abap.js"></script> before the bootstrap. I only create two BSP Applikations. I doen#t have a launchpad. Is it also possible ?  Where do i defnde the action which i should take ?

Comment: Seems that cross app navigation is working only for Fiori launchpad. For standalone app you probably have to use just url

Comment: Ok, do you the way how I can implement an URL. I just call the url with the other bsp applicaiton an the parameters ? Thanks

Comment: if both apps implemented on the same system you apparently can use relative url starting with "/sap/bc...". And you add parameters in the usual way (I imagine) with "?" and "&".

Comment: ok thank i am not a expert. How can i call the url in the application ?

Comment: should be like this: window.location.replace("-- url with parameters here --");

Comment: ok thanks! I hope the last question:) I have a development and test system how can i implement that the link reffers to the right system ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is:

```
window.location.replace("-- url with parameters here --")
```

The right system is : window.location.host

Answer (score 0):

I have a same issue.
SAPUI5 provide sap.m.URLHelper which contains [redirect method](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.URLHelper.html#redirect) :

```
sap.m.URLHelper.redirect(sURL, bNewWindow?)
```

I think SAPUI5 do the same thing than window.location.replace() but more SAPUI5-friendly.